# Join datetimes of DataFrames and forward fill data

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have two pandas DataFrames:

DataFrame `a`

```
2013-03-25 13:15:00     1
2013-03-26 13:15:00     2
2013-03-28 13:15:00     4
2013-03-29 13:15:00     5
```

and DataFrame `b`

```
2013-03-25 13:15:00    25
2013-03-27 13:15:00    15
2013-03-28 13:15:00     5
2013-03-29 13:15:00    10
```

I am trying to join the dates and forward fill the values. Right now I am doing it like this:

```
ab = pd.concat([a, b], axis=1)
ab.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)

a = ab.ix[:,0]
b = ab.ix[:,1]
```

So, `ab` is

```
2013-03-25 13:15:00     1    25
2013-03-26 13:15:00     2   NaN
2013-03-27 13:15:00   NaN    15
2013-03-28 13:15:00     4     5
2013-03-29 13:15:00     5    10
```

and then

```
2013-03-25 13:15:00     1    25
2013-03-26 13:15:00     2    25
2013-03-27 13:15:00     2    15
2013-03-28 13:15:00     4     5
2013-03-29 13:15:00     5    10
```

This has two disadvantages. Firstly, `a` and `b` are Series now. Secondly, this solution wouldn't work for multi-column DataFrames. Is it possible to just do this for `a` and `b` *in place* without going the way over `ab`. This seems like a fairly standard process. What am I missing?

**Edit:**

```
a.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 4 entries, 2013-03-25 13:15:00 to 2013-03-29 13:15:00
Data columns (total 1 columns):
icap    4 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1)
memory usage: 64.0 bytes
```

`b` is equivalent.

Comment: sorry are you wanting an outer merge: `a.merge(b, how='outer').ffill()`? I don't know if the dates are your index or a column, you need to clarify this

Comment: That would return a Data Frame with 2 columns right? I want to `a` and `b` be to modified.

Comment: So you want `a.combine_first(b).ffill()`? Also you've not answered the question as to what your df structure is, can you post `a.info()` and `b.info()`, thanks

Comment: This is about avoiding `a = ab.ix[:,0]` and `b = ab.ix[:,1]`. `a` and `b` are the results `ab` is just a computational step. Your solutions both return a 2 column DataFrame.

Comment: You can't update both dfs in place in a one liner, you can either update 1 or create a new df, not update both, additionally why don't you just assign back the result of the merge, I don't see anything wrong with doing that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple solution to modify the two DataFrames `a` and `b` in the desired way without merging or joining them is to use their index.

```
index_joined = a.index
index_joined = index_joined.union(b.index)
a.reindex(index=index_joined, method='ffill')
b.reindex(index=index_joined, method='ffill')
```

Answer (score 2):

I think in your case using [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html#pandas.DataFrame.combine_first) combined with `ffill` will give you what you want:

```
In [46]:
a.combine_first(b).ffill()

Out[46]:
                     a   b
index                     
2013-03-25 13:15:00  1  25
2013-03-26 13:15:00  2  25
2013-03-27 13:15:00  2  15
2013-03-28 13:15:00  4   5
2013-03-29 13:15:00  5  10
```

This will join and align on indices taking the union of both dfs, this will introduce `NaN` values which you can fill using `ffill`

From the result of the above you can just assign back the cols of interest, also it looks like what you really want is to reindex using the union of the indices:

```
In [48]:
a.reindex(a.index.union(b.index)).ffill()

Out[48]:
                     a
index                 
2013-03-25 13:15:00  1
2013-03-26 13:15:00  2
2013-03-27 13:15:00  2
2013-03-28 13:15:00  4
2013-03-29 13:15:00  5
```

So you can do this for both dfs without having to perform any merging/combining